# UVA Minesweeper Wrong Answer in C

Tags: c, minesweeper

I've been working on the UVA challenge 10189 : Minesweeper, and I keep getting Wrong Answer as a verdict though my code works perfectly for the test cases proposed (and additional test cases I come up with). I found a good deal of posts here debugging codes for this problem, but none of them fits my case.

I'd be grateful if any of you guys can help me see what's wrong with my code.

**Problem :**

> Have you ever played Minesweeper? It’s a cute little game which comes within a certain Operating
>   System which name we can’t really remember. Well, the goal of the game is to find where are all the
>   mines within a M × N field. To help you, the game shows a number in a square which tells you how
>   many mines there are adjacent to that square. For instance, supose the following 4 × 4 field with 2
>   mines (which are represented by an ‘*’ character):

```
*...
....
.*..
....
```

> If we would represent the same field placing the hint numbers described above, we would end up
>   with:

```
*100
2210
1*10
1110
```

> As you may have already noticed, each square may have at most 8 adjacent squares.

**Input**

> The input will consist of an arbitrary number of fields. The first line of each field contains two integers
>   n and m (0 < n, m ≤ 100) which stands for the number of lines and columns of the field respectively.
>   The next n lines contains exactly m characters and represent the field.
>   Each safe square is represented by an ‘.’ character (without the quotes) and each mine square
>   is represented by an ‘*’ character (also without the quotes). The first field line where n = m = 0
>   represents the end of input and should not be processed.

**Output**

> For each field, you must print the following message in a line alone:
>   Field #x:
>   Where x stands for the number of the field (starting from 1). The next n lines should contain the
>   field with the ‘.’ characters replaced by the number of adjacent mines to that square. There must be
>   an empty line between field outputs.

**Sample Input :**

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
3 5
**...
.....
.*...
0 0
```

**Sample Output :**

```
Field #1:
*100
2210
1*10
1110

Field #2:
**100
33200
1*100
```

**Source Code :**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//the two boundaries functions check whether 
//the corner indices of the "sub-grid" are within the boundaries of the field

int BoundariesTop(int i){   
    if (0 <= i-1)
        return (i-1);
    else 
        return 0;
}

int BoundariesBottom(int i, int n) {
    if (i+1 < n)
        return (i+1);   
    else 
        return (n-1);   
}

//CheckBomb is used to check every "sub-grid" (one cell + 8 adjacents)
//and count the number of bombs it contains.

void checkBomb(int spotI, int spotJ, int topI, int topJ, int bottomI, int bottomJ, int field[101][101]){
    int i, cnt = 0,j;

    for(i = topI; i <= bottomI; i++){
        for(j = topJ; j <= bottomJ; j++){
            if(field[i][j] == -1)
                cnt++;
        }
    }
    if(field[spotI][spotJ] != -1)
        field[spotI][spotJ]= cnt;
}

int main (void){

    int r, c, i, j, field[101][101], c1, z1, c2, z2, cnt = 0;
    char cell, temp;

    while (scanf("%d %d",&r,&c) && (r != 0 && c != 0)) {
        cnt++;
        //get the field
        //replace symbols with integer for computation purposes.
        for(i = 0; i<r; i++) {
            scanf("%c",&temp);
            for (j = 0; j<c; j++) {
                scanf("%c",&cell);
                if (cell == '*')
                    field[i][j] = -1;
                else if (cell == '.')
                    field[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        // Select and send sub-grid to be checked in function : checkBomb   
        for(i = 0; i<r; i++){
            for(j = 0; j<c; j++){
                //(c1,z1) are coordinates of top left of sub-grid
                c1 = BoundariesTop(i);
                z1 = BoundariesTop(j);
                //(c2,z2) are coordinates of bottom right of sub-grid
                c2 = BoundariesBottom(i,r);
                z2 = BoundariesBottom(j,c);
                checkBomb(i,j,c1,z1,c2,z2,field);
            }
        }

        // Print Result

        printf("Field #%d:",cnt);
        for(i = 0; i<r; i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j<c; j++) {
                if (field[i][j] == -1)
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf("%d",field[i][j]);
            }

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) your link is dead, and 2) your question should be more self-contained. What do you want to do ? What output do you expect ? What output are you getting ?

Comment: I will try to copy paste the problem. The link was supposed to answer your questions. Sorry about that.

Comment: maybe It requires a newline between the answer and answers ? __"There must be an empty line between field outputs."__

Comment: I did include a new line between the outputs, but I couldn't handle the case of printing a new line after the last output. I got a compilation error, though my code compiled & run perfectly on my computer.